# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, metrics, open-telemetry

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.kafka.internal.OpenTelemetryMetricsReporter exception is seen when using java 15 with spring-kafka version 2.3.3 due to which data is not getting ingested to kafka producer.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-kafka-clients-2.6</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId> spring-kafka </artifactId>
<version>   2.3.3.RELEASE  </version>
```

Comment: well, I don't see a dependency to javaagent, while the package of that class seems to be in that lib

Comment: Hello bellaSpring, can you upgrade the kafka version because i show in the documentation of spring-kafa version 2.3.3 has some vulnerabilities and it is deprecated. Documentation reference: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: I am running my spring application using the following :
java -javaagent:./opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -jar nsl-search-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: hi @JayKanara I have tried with 2.5.1 relese,still no luck..my springboot starter parent is of 2.3.5 Relese

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from upgrading that? For example, Spring 3 has been available for months. And why Java 15 instead of LTS release like 17?

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace and / or a small reproduction app? There's not a lot of information to go off of here.

Comment: I am running my spring application using java -javaagent:../../../../Downloads/opentelemetry-javaagent-1.20.2.jar -Dotel.instrumentation.kafka.metric-reporter.enabled=false -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
when Dotel.instrumentation.kafka.metric-reporter.enabled=true i am getting the above mentioned error but on disabling message is pushed to kafka without error

Comment: Please help on how I can resolve this even with metrics enabled